# Camel SFTP with username with special characters

Tags: java, apache-camel, sftp

In Camel (2.15.0) call to the SFTP ([docs](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html)) as such:

```
String uri = "sftp://foo.co.uk?username=Me+Admin&privateKeyFile=/my/id_rsa&knownHostsFile=/my/known_hosts&preferredAuthentications=publickey"
producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(uri, fileContents, "CamelFileName", fullFilePath);
```

Results in SFTP attempt for user `Me Admin`. Clearly the `+` is replaced by a space.
I tried to url-encode this (`Me%2DAdmin`), still replaced by space (`Me Admin`).
Tried to encode it twice, now the SFTP attempt is for username `Me%2DAdmin`.
Anyone has an idea how do I get Camel to SFTP for a user with a `+` in the username? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok to answer my own question, changing the request url from `sftp://host?username=user` to `sftp://user@host` fixes the problem. The username still has to be encoded once:

```
String uri = "sftp://Me%2DAdmin@foo.co.uk?privateKeyFile=/my/id_rsa&knownHostsFile=/my/known_hosts&preferredAuthentications=publickey"
producerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(uri, fileContents, "CamelFileName", fullFilePath);
```

Comment: See here how to configure uris with passwords, http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-configure-endpoints.html

Answer (score 2):

It’s always good to surround the username/password with RAW() tag. For example sftp:user@hostname?password=RAW(password@123)